# No entiendo el error al pasar de 'const char' a 'char'

Tags: c++, programación-bajo-nivel

Inicializo mis variables asi:

```
char nombre[24];
char EquipoRival[24];
char EquipoLocal[24];
```

Y mas adelante le quiero asignar un valor a 'Equipo Rival' al azar, de tres posibles, de esta forma:

```
switch (random_Rival) {
    case '0' :
        cout << "Tu rival es Santos\n";
        EquipoRival = "Puebla";
        break;
    case '1' :
        cout << "Tu rival es Monterrey\n";
        EquipoRival = "Monterrey";
        break;
    case '2' :
        cout << "Tu rival es Tigres\n";
        EquipoRival = "Tigres";
        break;
    default :
        cout << "Error... chale";
        break;
}
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

*[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'const char [7]' to 'char [24]'*

¿Alguien sabe cual es el problema?

Comment: Si quieres usar el operador de asignación para asignar una nueva cadena, debes declarar un puntero que apunta a la dirección base de una cadena literal. Ejemplo: `const char* p; p = "Test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error muy común. Las cadenas de caracteres no funcionan como con otros tipos de variable, no puedes usar el operador de asignación `=` como has hecho hasta ahora (Excepto en la declaración de la cadena).

Para hacer la asignación con cadenas tienes que usar strcpy, de la librería cstring.

```
char EquipoLocal[24] = "Nombre Aleatorio"; //En la declaración esto es correcto

                                //Fuera de la declaración no
EquipoRival = "Puebla";         // Forma erronea
strcpy(EquipoRival, "Puebla");  //Forma correcta
```

Comment: Mejor aún sería usar `std::string`.

Comment: Si, claro, pero si está empezando puede ser que no le permitan usar strings (A mi no me lo permitían). No es el mejor código, pero creo que se aprende mas.

Comment: "*puede ser que no le permitan usar strings*" ¿Quién? ¿Por qué?

Comment: A mi en la universidad no me permitieron usar strings hasta bien entrados en herencia y polimorfismo. Se usaban los ´char*´ para enseñarnos las implicaciones de la memoria dinámica.

Comment: Pues en tu universidad enseñaban a programar de manera nefasta.

Comment: Ok, lo anoto y lo cuelgo en la nevera,

Comment: Te creo (presente indicativo de creer).

Answer (score 3):

En C++ todos los datos tienen un tipo asociado, incluidos los literales de texto, por ejemplo el literal de texto `"Puebla"` tiene como tipo `const char[7]`.

El tipo `const char[7]` se corresponde a una formación<sup>1</sup> de siete elementos, cada uno de los elementos es un carácter (`char`) de sólo lectura (constante, `const`). Tus variables `nombre`, `EquipoRival`, `EquipoLocal` tienen como tipo `char[24]`, es decir: son una formación de veinticuatro  elementos carácter de lectura/escritura (no son `const`).

En C++ no se permite asignar formaciones a formaciones, menos aún formaciones de tamaño distinto (formación de siete elementos en una formación de veinticuatro) y menos aún formaciones con permisos diferentes (elementos de sólo lectura en elementos de lectura/escritura).

La manera habitual de guardar cadenas de texto en C++ no es el uso de formaciones de caracteres si no usando el objeto `std::string`:

```
std::string nombre;
std::string EquipoRival;
std::string EquipoLocal;
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de tu código se puede observar en una situación fundamental: recuerda que, en esencia, estás creando un array de caracteres, lo que quiere decir que para hacer cualquier tipo de modificación, es necesario ceñirse a los principios que rigen a los arrays.

Como primera medida, el definir un array solo indicando su longitud sin lo que va a contener está contraindicado pues puede derivar en que se cometan errores. Por ejemplo:

```
char EquipoRival[24]; // no es recomendado

char EquipoRival[24] = "Puebla"; // es recomendado. 
// Además los elementos toman una posición dentro del array.
```

Luego, como segunda medida, se ha cometido un error de suma importancia al asignar nuevos elementos a contener en el array.

```
EquipoRival = "puebla"; // esto está mal.
```

La variable `nombre` no indica todo el vector con sus elementos, en C/C++ usar el nombre de un array indica su dirección de memoria.

Para la asignación de valores está el uso de las funciones `strcpy`, `strncpy`, o funciones más seguras como `strlcpy` (sistemas basados en BSD Y en MAC OS X) o `strcpy_s` (para Windows). En general, su uso dependerá de los requerimientos que se tenga según la plataforma, ya que no todas son portables.

```
strcpy(EquipoRival, "Puebla");
strlcpy(EquipoRival, "Puebla", 24);  // 24 es el tamaño de EquipoRival
```

> No se recomienda el uso de `strncpy` pues puede derivar en que tu array se quede sin el último elemento `NULL` o `'\0'`. Para más información visita la pregunta [Why does strncpy not null terminate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453876/why-does-strncpy-not-null-terminate).